# How to properly bind greater and lesser values in the loop in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I need to bind properly the greater and lesser value in the initial binding in the `loop`. The values are provided in ad-hoc order, so I need to distinguish them first. The `loop` itself is used inside an anonymous function.

So, I need to do something like:

```clj
(#(loop [divident %1 divisor %2] (some-recursion)) greater lesser)
```

or, this in case of swapped arguments:

```clj
(#(loop [divident %2 divisor %1] (some-recursion)) lesser greater)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For two numbers, the simplest approach is just to use `max` and `min` in the `loop` binding:

```
(#(loop [dividend (max %2 %1)
         divisor (min %2 %1)]
    (println (format "larger: %d   smaller: %d" dividend divisor)))
  2 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need values to be in order from greater to lesser or lesser to greater then you could use the functions `sort` and `sort-by`. For instance:

```
(sort [1 7 4 6])
;;=> (1 4 6 7)
(sort-by - [1 7 4 6])
;;=> (7 6 4 1)
```

So for two numbers you can easily destructure the sort result:

```
(let [[lesser greater] (sort [7 1])]
  (println lesser greater))
;;=> 1 7
```

Applying that to the `loop`:

```
(defn x-1 []
  (#(let [[lesser greater] (sort [%1 %2])]
      (loop [bigger greater
             smaller lesser]
        (println smaller bigger))) 7 1))
;;=> 1 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this is a proper solution, but: we can do *any* initial binding and than do the appropriate binding switch in the first recursion loop.

Here is an example of implementation of the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) as an anonymous function:

```clj
(#(loop [dd %1 dr %2]
  (if (zero? (rem dd dr))
    dr
    (recur dr (rem dd dr))))
  858 1023)
;; -> 33

(#(loop [dd %1 dr %2]
  (if (zero? (rem dd dr))
    dr
    (recur dr (rem dd dr))))
  1023 858)
;; -> 33
```